# How to handle circular dependency between claim and proof?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have recently asked a [question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/32043/is-it-possible-to-read-the-contents-of-a-pin-locked-iphone-5) about a [claim](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/115044/why-cant-the-fbi-read-the-key-embedded-in-the-iphones-secure-chip-rom-directly) made by infosec.SE users which is, in simple words, "FBI can unlock an iPhone without Apple helping". This question was closed a a duplicate of [this one](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/31989/does-fbi-not-require-assistance-from-apple-to-unlock-the-san-bernadino-terrorist), which references the initial claim as proof. So in the end, the claim made by infosec.SE users is effectively supported by itself.

I can see only two resolutions of this [logical fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reasoning):

- either "FBI can do X" is considered common knowledge. In that case, sorry for wasting everybody's time.
- or, aswers on infosec.SE constitute a proof for Snowden's tweet, but can themselves be questioned as a claim. In that case, why is my question a duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a circular dependency here (disclaimer, I voted to close your question).

The [original question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/31989/does-fbi-not-require-assistance-from-apple-to-unlock-the-san-bernadino-terrorist) can be answered differently, without referring to infosec.se.

If you are not satisfied with the current answer, you can offer a [bounty](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/bounty). There's a specific bounty clause for that.

> **Authoritative reference needed**
>
> Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.

In particular, the community voting on infosec.se is more reliable than Snowden's statements, which is why we have the current answer on that question. However, a new answer, based on more official sources, would certainly belong there, so there's no reason to ask a new question.

In general, it is considered bad form to ask duplicate questions if the answers on one do not satisfy you.

Comment: First, let me mention that I didn't create a duplicate knowingly (if you check the edit history, you'll see that I initially phrased my question differently, and my initial search didn't include the word `iPhone`). I take the blame for posting a dupe though.

Comment: Second, bounties don't really help in my experience; people either do have the answer (and will post it, or at least give a hint in comments), or they don't. The only bounty I was happy with was to reward an existing answer which I liked.

Comment: And finally, I don't know see the point of insisting on this topic. If citing infosec.SE (or wikipedia for that matter) constitutes a valid answer, I'd rather not ask. I'm not being judgmental here, I just had different expectations (like a reference to a research paper, a link to a company offering such services, a plausible description of such process). A simple "yes, it is possible" is not going to cut it for me, no matter the source.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev citing infosec.se is a valid answer, but it is a weak answer, it's perfectly reasonable to want more reputable sources.

Answer (score 1):

Both questions have answers severely lacking facts. There are many opinions, people claiming common knowledge, and I sense many upvotes resulting from distrust of the FBI or related agencies (people 'making a point' by voting).

Maybe we should shut these questions down and point to [Why does the FBI ask Apple for help to decrypt an iPhone?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/32886/why-does-the-fbi-ask-apple-for-help-to-decrypt-an-iphone). The folks at [Crypto StackExchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) go into the facts much better.

Comment: Nice read, thanks! It's funny that crypto.SE folks **actually assume the exact opposite** of infosec.SE, namely that hardware key cannot be read directly from silicon. I'm kind of tempted to post an exact opposite of [this answer](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/31993/29073) to skeptics, citing crypto.SE question as a "reference".